Wordpress editing interface cuts off in Google Chrome but not Firefox
As of yesterday, when editing a WordPress page or post in Google Chrome, the top and right areas are cut off, this includes the Publish/Save button which I can only see part of now. I tried this in Firefox, and it still looks fine. Chrome is my preferred browser, so I would like to fix this and continue editing in Chrome.
Here is what the top looks like in Google Chrome (you can see where things such as the save button are cut off)
Editing area in Chrome
Here is what the top looks like in Firefox (this is how I want that top area to look in Google Chrome)
Editing area in Firefox
I have tried updating plugins, updating Google Chrome, logging in and out of WordPress, but it still looks off in Chrome. It's like the editing interface suddenly needs some additional top and right padding

Welcome! We cannot debug via screenshots. Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

Disabling the Yoast SEO plugin seems to resolve the issue. I guess that icon going away frees up space in that top bar of the editing interface. However, this is still a problem if you want to keep using the Yoast SEO plugin. I have tried just removing it from that top bar, but the issue comes back. The only way I have found to resolve the issue is to deactivate the plugin completely.
Screenshot with Yoast SEO icon circled
